# For cycle [C/java like syntax]

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm

So here I am with this simple question

Consider these two for cycles and please
explain to me if there's any difference
between the two ways of writing

method 1 :

```
  for(i=(max-1) ; i>=0 ; i--){ do-some-stuff }
```

method 2 :

```
  for(i=max ; i>0 ; i--)     { do-some-stuff }
```

the reason I'm asking this is because today at school
while we were seeing some Java functions, there was 
this palindrome method wich would use as max the
length of the word passed to it and the method used 
to cycle trough the for was the first, can anyone 
clarify me why the person who writed that piece of 
code prefeered using that method ?

Comment: "for cycle" sounds really strange !

Comment: @RafeKettler - incorrect, there is definitely a difference between the two. The range of `i` in the two scenarios is different.

Comment: It depends on where `i` is used in `do-some-stuff` or the loop is simply a mechanism to repeat `max` times.

Comment: BTW, I've also seen `for (i = max; --i >= 0; ) { ... }`. I would pick the construct that is most idiomatic to your team/project and just stick with it.

Comment: Both are inferior to the arrow operator, `i = max; while(i --> 0) {}` which is read as "While i goes to zero".

Comment: As a side note, I avoid `i>=0`, in case someone changes `i` to `unsigned` later.

Comment: @glowcoder: `i=max-1`, you're range isn't quite right.

Comment: @MooingDuck oh you're right :-) Too late to edit though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there's a big difference - in the version, the range is `[0, max-1]`. In the second version, it's `[1, max]`. If you're trying to access a 0-based array with `max` elements, for example, the second version will blow up and the first won't.

If the *order* in which the loop ran didn't matter, I'd personally use the more idiomatic ascending sequence:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
```

... but when descending, the first form gives the same range of values as this, just in the opposite order.

Answer (score 3):

Both the loops will iterate `max` times. But the ranges would be different:

- First loop's range would be `max - 1` to `0` (both inclusive)
- Second second loop's range would be `max` to `1`.

Therefore, if you are using `i` as an array index, or doing some work which is a function of `i` , dependent of `i`, then it will create problems for the terminal values (for example `0` is considered in the first one, where as not by the second one). But if you simply want to iterate the loop `max` nos of times , and do some work which is independent of the value of `i`, then there is no difference.